# IE9 Window Loses Focus due to jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9

In our product, we're using the most recent development version of jQuery Mobile in our ASP.NET website. Each and every time we do an ASP.NET postback, the browser window goes to the back of the screen.

Example:

- Maximize any window. Example: Visual
  Studio, Word, Windows Explorer.
- Maximize IE9 over it. IE9 is the only
  thing you see on the screen.
- Click on a button in our solution that does
  a postback.
- IE9 is no longer visible.
  Whatever was behind it now has focus
  (and fills the screen, as it is
  maximized)

Only workarounds I know:

- Don't include the jQuery mobile scripts.
- Ensure IE9 is the only maximized window in Windows.

I don't know what jQuery Mobile is doing in the background and am assuming this is a bug in IE9 that will eventually be fixed. However, if you had any tips on how to prevent it from happening in the meantime, that would be great.

Edit: Seems it isn't on every postback. It is on every postback that performs a Response.Redirect. I should add that all my postback are actually utilizing ASP.NET AJAX, not full postbacks.

Comment: PS: I am very surprised that javascript can affect operating system windows in this way.

Comment: do you have your application in debug mode attached to VS?

Comment: Nope. Even does it when done on an external server.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but only when theres just one tab open in IE9. If you open another tab, with a random site, this bug will not occur.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but for people coming here from Google:

I ran into this same issue today. It seems this lose focus behavior is what IE does when you trigger the blur event on the window object. This was the code that caused this issue for me:

```
$(document.activeElement).blur();
```

activeElement will default to the body element when there are no other elements in focus, and the blur event then bubbles up to the window. To fix this I simply did a check like:

```
if (document.activeElement != $('body')[0]) {
    $(document.activeElement).blur();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't have time to test it properly as we found another workaround (Chrome Frame, heh) :)

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem with IE10 and jQuery 1.7.2.
I found these lines in my code:

```
$(document.activeElement).blur();
```

and

```
$(':focus').blur();
```

So, adding simple .not('body') resolves the problem:

```
$(document.activeElement).not('body').blur();
$(':focus').not('body').blur();
```

Comment: Well written answer and elegant solution, worked for me, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This same issue seems to occur with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

When using IE 10, with a single tab open and another window on the same monitor, if you open a popup it will send the browser to the background.

To fix this you have to edit the _handleDocumentFocusIn function.  You need to change the line(10391) that reads:

`target.blur();`

to

```
if (targetElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "body")
{
    target.blur();
}
```

I made a pull request so hopefully this will be included in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this link to anybody who is experiencing more of this continued mess.  I am seeing the problem on IE 9 and IE 10 on a window.location = 'BLAH', from within the Angular location resource.

This doesn't seem to solve the problem for me, but it may help others:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600156/en-us