# IE loses focus or goes behind all windows during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0 and jQuery UI plugin. I have a page containing a jquery Tab control. When I load this page, the browser goes behind of all open windows only when the browser is Internet Explorer. It seems that focus has been lost but in the taskbar it shows itself focused/active. But page load completes behind.It goes behind after the header has been loaded. I've search on the net but didn't find anything helpful. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of IE? And where is the code, so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It's not clear to me but I've removed a jquery file from being loaded/added by script tag in the header section and it worked for me. The file was eye.js that had been used with jquery color picker plugin.

Comment: just solved the same issue. It's crazy that there aren't more google results for this bug. Seems to be a major issue with this plugin

Comment: Glad to know that and be aware of IE.:-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but for people coming from Google, I've come up with a solution to this issue. I've posted it as an answer on another question which is similar to this one:

[IE9 Window Loses Focus due to jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657371/ie9-window-loses-focus-due-to-jquery-mobile/12150059#12150059)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not a jQuery, Code Igniter problem. Sounds more like a temporary problem with IE itself.

What OS are you using? Windows XP?

Comment: Windows XP and IE 6,7 and 8 is behaving in same way.

Comment: Try restarting. I highly doubt it's an actual document problem.